# Sharepoint 2010 DataViewWebPart with Parameter

Tags: sharepoint-2010, parameters, common-table-expression, dataviewwebpart

So after much frustration I finally created a sql server data source with a single parameter inside of Sharepoint 2010 Designer. The query is a common table expression (CTE) which runs just fine from SQL Server Management Studio. The parameter is an integer (Int32).

What I would like happen is to have a textbox that the user can enter the number in and then the page will retrieve the results of the query.

My questions are:

1) Is this even possible?

2) If so, how do I do it? I have looked high and low and cannot seem to have any luck finding help on something that one would think would be fairly simple.